# Python-need help on how to make a crpyter shifting+1 on alphabet

Tags: python

Im making a menu and everything in it is perfect but what i need now is to make a crypter in a sense by when the end user inputs a sentence, all the letters he/she inputs will shift up the alphabet by +1 so example:

```
Input: The Dog Jumped
Expected output: uif!eph!kvnqfe
```

What i have coded:

```
def crypts():
print()
print("You said the following:")
time.sleep(1)
sentenc = input("Please enter your sentence: ")
print(sentenc)
print()
print("Your crypted sentence is:")
senten = crp(sentenc)
time.sleep(1)
print(senten)
again()
```

Then here is what i need help with in solving

```
def crp(c):
dont know what to type here what so ever, i am gone blank sadly:z
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add one to the `ord` values and convert to a character again using `chr`:

```
s="The Dog Jumped"

In [14]: enc = "".join([chr(ord(c)+1) for c in s])   
In [15]: enc
Out[15]: 'Uif!Eph!Kvnqfe'    
In [16]: dec = "".join([chr(ord(c)-1) for c in enc])    
In [17]: dec
Out[17]: 'The Dog Jumped'
```

Comment: I add:
def crp(c):
    s=c
    print("".join(chr((ord(c)+1))  for c in s))

Output then has the answer plus =  none after the answer, what my doing wrong? Also is there a more convenient way of doing this something like what i had in my other ones, im not a type of guy for that type of coding. Thanks though for directing me in a sense:)

Comment: Because you are not returning anything, you need to return `"".join(chr((ord(c)+1)) for c in s)`, I don't think you can get much simpler than how I have provided

Comment: Ahh i get you now, i was printing it like a fail so it wasnt exactly completing the task. Is there any other way of doing this like another solution you may in completing this?

Comment: There are numerous ways but none that are going to be any simpler. What is wrong with using ord?

Comment: Nothing exactly wrong with ord its just the way i have my program set, i dont particularly have mine set towards the way you have the answer there if you get me. Like for reversing my sentence i would use:
n = len(sentence)
    x=""
    for i in range(n-1,-1,-1):
        x += sentence[i]
    return x.
Thats something i was hoping to achieve in doing the +1 up alphabet thing haha

Comment: That looks like a lot more work than a simple list comp! I don't think `x += sentence[i]` is going to do much in the way of shifting to the next letter.